# Mapstruct generate Constructor for dependency injection

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to generate an implementation in MapStruct that will create a constructor for me that I can use for constructor-based dependency injection. I have learned that I can't use constructor-injection in the mapper definition(seen below), but how do I make it so that my generated class has one?

I have tried below:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = Dependency.class, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public abstract class MapStructTest {
private Dependency dependency;

@Mapping(source = "field", target "target")
@Mapping(target = "target2", ignore = true)
@AfterMapping
public final void runAfter() {
//dostuff for target2
    }
}
```

With no success. My class is generated, looks ok, except there is no constructor. How do I define my mapper so that I get a constructor I can work with in the implementation?

Best regards,
Prince of Sweden

Comment: Just a note: MapStruct doesn't generate constructors, Lombok does.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Oh, so I have to use Lombok in my mapper definition somewhere to get it in the impl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MapStruct does not support calling constructors for abstract classes. You have to have a default empty constructor.

In order to inject `Dependency` you can use `@Autowired` on your field or add a setter with `@Autowired`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that instead. I would love to use constructor-based injection to be honest.

Comment: I think that there is a feature request for supporting constructor injection for this as well.

Comment: Yes, the feature request is found [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1973) and its goal is set to verison 2.0.