# Mapstruct's generated mapper doesn't call the super constructor. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have this mapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(CardMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CardMapper {
```

And this mapper decorator:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {

    private final CardMapper delegate;
```

Notice it has a constructor (for injection purposes). When Mapstruct generates an implementation, it looks like this:

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-10-10T13:40:01+0300",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.5 (Amazon.com Inc.)"
)
@Component
@Primary
public class CardMapperImpl extends CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private CardMapper delegate;

// methods
```

It doesn't compile since the implementation doesn't call the `super` constructor. How do I fix it?

I know Mapstruct [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537340/mapstruct-generate-constructor-for-dependency-injection) calling super constructors. Does it mean the only way forward I have is to either use field or setter injection?

**UPD:** Does it really not support constructors? The code below must be valid according to the [docs](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/api/org/mapstruct/DecoratedWith.html):

```java
 public abstract class PersonMapperDecorator implements PersonMapper {

     private PersonMapper delegate;

     public PersonMapperDecorator(PersonMapper delegate) {
         this.delegate = delegate;
     }

     @Override
     public PersonDto personToPersonDto(Person person) {
         PersonDto dto = delegate.personToPersonDto( person );
         dto.setName( person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() );

         return dto;
     }
 }
```

This wouldn't work unless Mapstruct generated a constructor with a `super` call in it

Comment: You can tell MapStruct to use constructors using the `injectionStrategy` attribute of `@Mapper`. However, I'm not sure if it then calls the super constructor, or only stores its own `delegate` field.

Comment: Your design looks wrong. Your implementation has got two fields both named `delegate`, one declared in the superclass and one declared in the class itself. Was this what you wanted? What for?

Comment: @OleV.V. first, it's not exactly my code, I try to improve it. Second, the second class is the  class Mapstruct generated, no human wrote it