# Can my decorated mapper be a @Component and be tested as a unit as well?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

If I want to test my decorated mapper as a unit, I need this setup:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "default")
@DecoratedWith(CardMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CardMapper {
```

```java
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {

    private CardMapper delegate;

    public CardMapperDecorator(CardMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
```

If I want my decorated mapper to be a `@Component`, I need this setup (since Mapstruct can't generate a constructor with a `super` call in it in the implementation class)

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(CardMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CardMapper {
```

```java
@Component
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {

    private CardMapper delegate;

    @Autowired // I can also autowire the field directly
    public void setDelegate(CardMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
```

I want both to test the mapper as a unit (and avoid bootstrapping the context) *and* make it a `@Component` (it is being injected elsewhere)

Can I do it?

**UPD:** *M. Deinum* suggested adding an extra constructor. If this is what was meant:

```java
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {
    @Autowired
    private CardMapper delegate; // for Spring injection

    public CardMapperDecorator(CardMapper delegate) { // for default injection
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
// decorator logic
```

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "default") // this is absolutely necessary for my unit tests to pass
@DecoratedWith(CardMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CardMapper {

// mapping methods
```

unfortunately, it still doesn't work. From SonarQube:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'by.afinny.credit.mapper.CardMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
```

Comment: `@Component` on an `abstract` class is pointless. Also  why would making it an `@Component` prevent you from creating your own instance, the testing isn't any different as you would do otherwise. I also find it strange that MapStruct would be able to generate the proper constructor with `default` mode but not in `spring` mode.

Comment: @M.Deinum Mapstruct indeed [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537340/mapstruct-generate-constructor-for-dependency-injection) that. Basically, I need a constructor for the `default` mode and no constructor for the `spring` mode

Comment: @M.Deinum Mapstruct generates a class that extends my decorator

Comment: Just use default mode and write an `@Bean` method to make it a spring component. To make it a spring bean it doesn't need to be an `@Component` it needs to be available in the context.

Comment: Hmm. I would expect that setting the injection strategy to constructor to fix this. https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#injection-strategy. Hmm on hindsight that doesn't apply to the decorator it appears.

Comment: Next to the `@Bean` method there is also nothing preventing you from writing that constructor, add a nno-args constructor and annotate the fiedl (as mentioned in the documentation). I would expect that would make it work for both.

Comment: @M.Deinum What am I going to create in that `@Bean` method? It's a generated class

Comment: The generated class is still accessible. But as stated before nothing is preventing you from adding multiple constructors, hence I would go with that. Or instead of a decorator add pre/post mapping methods.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you mean this: `@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {
    @Autowired
    private CardMapper delegate;

    public CardMapperDecorator(CardMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
`? I'm not sure it works

Comment: @M.Deinum also, what should be inside my `@Mapper` annotation: `default` or `spring` (to satisfy both of my needs)?

Comment: I don't get both of your needs, why would you need multiple mechanisms in your application. I don't see it. The code in comments in unreadable please don't post additional code/cionfig etc. as comments.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's because the mapper is injected as a bean elsewhere. However, in order to test it as a unit (without Spring), my mapper decorator has to have a constructor with a parameter and the default component model (it seems)

Comment: Again no it doesn't. Use make it spring and add the constructor as I stated already. There is nothing preventing you from adding additional constructors. You are overthinking all of this.

Comment: @M.Deinum once I change `default` to `spring`, my unit test fails due to an NPE (the delegate is not initialized) so I do need that

Comment: I yield. Apparently I cannot explain it to you in an understandable way so I'll take my loss.

Comment: @M.Deinum just show the code, and no explanation will be necessary